# Insert data on virtual Datatable c#

Tags: c#

i'n trying to insert data to a datatable:

```
public DataTable dtproddisp;

        private void criarDatatable()
        {
            dtproddisp = new DataTable();
            //dtproddisp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(Int32)));
            dtproddisp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Codigo", typeof(Int32)));
            dtproddisp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Descricao", typeof(string)));
            dtproddisp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantidade", typeof(double)));
            dtproddisp.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtproddisp.Columns["Codigo"] };
```

So far so good, dtprodisp is created as public, columns added.
now comes the problem i need to insert data to codigo,descricao and quantidade from texbox.

textbox1 = Prdcodigo(Read only and invisible because i'n getting this from database);

textbox2 =  Pdescricao;

textbox3 = Pquantidade;

Button1 = Add;

so my question is how can i send to my dtprodisp datatable all the records filled on those 3 textboxes. After that i'll load my dtproddisp on a datagridview

Comment: workRow["CustLName"] = "Smith";  
workRow[1] = "Smith"; i've read it, but doens't work for me as i need the "Smith" comes from a textbox and not set

Comment: no, that is from the link you sent, was just telling you that it's not what i need as the link show how to add from code itself and not from a textbox

Comment: Bind the Controls to the DataTable. The binding specifies which Column each Control is bound to. -- You didn't specify a GUI Platform.